# simplificar um IF grande!

Tags: php, php-7

Tenho a seguinte condição para testar:

```
if (isset($_GET["cadastrarMembro"]) && (
                   $_SESSION["acesso"]["idAcesso"] == 3 
                   $_SESSION["acesso"]["idAcesso"] == 5 
                   $_SESSION["acesso"]["idAcesso"] == 6 
                   $_SESSION["acesso"]["idAcesso"] == 10 
                                         ) {

//FAZ ALGO AQUI
}
```

Gostaria de simplificar com algo parecido com isso:

```
if (isset($_GET["cadastrarMembro"]) && $_SESSION["acesso"]["idAcesso"] IN (3, 5, 6 , 10)) {
//FAZ ALGO AQUI
}
```

Como fazer isso?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if (isset($_GET["cadastrarMembro"]) && in_array($_SESSION["acesso"]["idAcesso"], [3, 5, 6, 10])) {
//FAZ ALGO AQUI
}
```

Comment: acabeu de conseguir aqui dessa forma if (isset($_GET["cadastrarMembro"]) && in_array($_SESSION["acesso"]["idAcesso"], array(3, 5, 6 , 9, 10))) {} mas o teu ficou melhor